# Returning null password when read decrypted password from decryppwd.sh file

Tags: java, password-encryption

I am working on Java web application that should get the decrypted password from .sh file.
(e.g file name: decryppwd.sh)

My issue is it returns a blank password when using variable inside the decryppwd.sh file.

```
E.g:
#decrypted password#
pwd='Welcome123'
echo pwd
#returns: ''
```

But if we directly use echo to return the password; it is returning the password from decryppwd.sh file.

```
E.g:
#decrypted password#
echo 'Welcome123'
#returns: Welcome123
```

**My code:**

```
public static String callPwdShellScript(String schema) throws IOException {
    String s = null;
    Process p =null;
    String hostname =null;
    String value2 ="oracle";
     

    try {
          p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“/usr/bin/bash /app/project/config/decryppwd.sh”);
        
      BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader commandResult = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buffer));
             String line = null;
             
                while((line = commandResult.readLine())!=null)
                    {     
                        value2 = line; 
            }   
  
        catch(IOException e)
         {        
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            logger.error("callPwdShellScript IOException: " + e.getMessage());  
         }
         catch(Exception e) {
             logger.error("callPwdShellScript Exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
         }
        
        return value2;   
}
```

Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: try appending `value2 = value2 + line; `

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: and clean up your code.  `throws IOException` - no it doesn't.  `String value2 ="oracle";` - why? `String s = null;` - not used.

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. See [tag:password-encryption] for why not. Hash them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by reading only 1st line of the BufferedReader.